# Unable to sign up to azure devops. Error : Oops! Something happened. Please check our support page for service updates, and try again later

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am unable to singup for azure devops. I am trying free sign up for educational purposes. I tried on multiple days getting same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I tried changing the Directory (Under Switch Directory Option) to **Default Directory** and it worked. I was using Google Chrome browser (incognito mode)
[image]